# dnx is not recognize to run asp.net 5 application

Tags: asp.net-core

- try to run Asp.Net 5 Application through command prompt by using command
  *C:\asp.net5App\src\asp.net5>dnx .web*
- error message that I am getting.
  *'dnx' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am tied of this thread, because it has so many misleading answers that happen to work for some people and not for others. But anyway this is what worked for me.

- Install visual studio 2015 (Enterprise)
- open **Developer Command Prompt for VS2015** and ran the following commands

  @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "&{$Branch='dev';iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1'))}"

the above installs .NET Version Manager (DNVM)

- Then i cd into the folder where dnvm has been installed e.g 
  cd /Users/johnny/.dnx/bin
- there i ran these commands

  dnvm upgrade -r coreclr   **(To install DNX for .NET Core)**

  dnvm upgrade -r clr      **(To install DNX for the full .NET Framework)**
- then i ran

  dnvm setup   **(to firmly setup the path)**
- then i got out of /Users/johnny/.dnx/bin and ran

where dnvm  = **C:\Users\johnny.dnx\bin\dnvm.cmd**

dnvm    = **produced a batch of commands options to be used**

Comment: Hey i may have left out one important thing, after all the above steps please  run this command **dnvm upgrade**  this l'l download a **DNX** , then you can run **dnx**

Answer (score 11):

Run `dnvm upgrade`.

If `dnvm` is not recognized, follow the instructions on the [Home repo](https://github.com/aspnet/home) to install it, then do the previous step.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you've got an active `runtime` before you can use `dnx`.

```
dnvm use
```